# How to interrupt MapView loading/rendering

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uistoryboardsegue

My application has a Scrollview, which remains hidden until the MapView is done rendering. However you can still go back to the home screen before MapView is done rendering.

My issue is that whenever I try to do this while the MapView is loading/rendering the segue doesn't work, and when it does the animation is buggy.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is anyway to interrupt the MapView loading/rendering?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by doing two steps:

**1)** Do your `mapView` loading and rendering task in **background**.

**2)** When you press `Home Button` put this line

```
[mapView stopRendering] // mapView is your mapView
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, a bit hasty on this answer, stopRendering doesn't appear to be a function that present in the mapView object?

Comment: Kindly see this for more detail https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapView

Comment: and this too for googlemaps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_layer

Comment: stopRending doesn't appear to be a function go mapview